# Is my formula for the CDF of negative binomial distribution right?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

Due to the differences in notation for the formula of the CDF of negative binomial distribution from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/negative-binomial-distribution) and [Vose Software](https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/NegativeBinomial.php), I decide to rewrite it in the way that I can easily understand.  We have:

$x$ number of trials, $x = \textrm{1, 2, ...}$

$r$ number of failures, $r = \textrm{1, 2, ... }x$

$k$ number of successes, $k = x - r = \textrm{0, 1, ... }$

$p$ probability of success, $0<p<1$

The formula for the CDF of binomial distribution is:

$$F_{X_k}(x)=P(X_k\leq x)=\sum_{i=1}^{x}{{k+i}\choose{i}}p^{k}{(1-p)}^{i}$$

Do I have it right?  Many thanks!

Comment: There are at least four ways of specifying a negative binomial distribution: number of attempts or number of successes/failures until a stated number of failures/successes occur

Comment: My convention for $x$, $r$ and $k$ defines it as the number of successes (starting from 0) out of the number of trials (starting from 1).

Comment: Your expression does not seem to contain $r$

Comment: Pardon the confusion, $k = x - r$.

Answer (score 1):

As in your question [Correct formulas for the mean and variance of negative binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/464393/1352) at CrossValidated, the different sites you link to seem to have different ideas of what $p$ is. The $p$ at ScienceDirect seems to be the probability of *failure*, whereas the $p$ at Wikipedia is the one of *success*. (The latter appears intuitively more appealing to me. R also uses the convention that the `prob` parameter to `rnbinom()` stands for the probability of *success*.)

Also as in the CV question and as [Henry notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657786/is-my-formula-for-the-cdf-of-negative-binomial-distribution-right#comment7517096_3657786), you need to take care of whether you define your random variable as counting the number of *trials* or of *failures* until you see $k$ successes. Or even as the number of trials or of successes until you see $r$ failures.

Your random variable $X_k$ apparently counts the number of failures until you see $k$ successes. This is almost exactly the formulation used in Wikipedia, except that Wikipedia's formulation counts the number of *successes* until we see a certain number of *failures*. (Conversely, R does it your way.) We can account for this by exchanging the definition of "success" and "failure", which amounts to changing $p$ in the Wikipedia article to $(1-p)$. (Also note that Wikipedia's $r$ is your $k$.) The PMF is then

$$ P(X_k=i) = {i+k-1 \choose i}p^k (1-p)^i. $$

For the CDF, we have to sum from zero (we may see zero failures) to the $x$ you want:

$$ P(X_k\leq x) = \sum_{i=0}^x P(X_k=i) = \sum_{i=0}^x{i+k-1 \choose i}p^k (1-p)^i. $$

This looks a little different from your formula, both in terms of the summation (which needs to start from zero, as above) and of a different binomial coefficient. I can't quite reconstruct where this comes from, but a little simulation in R appears to vindicate the CDF I propose (bars are simulation results, the black line gives my CDF, the red line yours):

[image]

```
rm(list=ls())

pp <- 0.3   # probability of success
kk <- 2 # number of successes

nn <- 10000
failures <- rnbinom(nn,size=kk,prob=pp) # gives number of *failures*, see ?rnbinom

cdf_sk <- Vectorize(function(xx) {
    ii <- 0:xx
    sum(choose(ii+kk-1,ii)*pp^kk*(1-pp)^ii)}, vectorize.args="xx")

cdf_muxo <- Vectorize(function(xx) {
    ii <- 1:xx
    sum(choose(kk+ii,ii)*pp^kk*(1-pp)^ii)}, vectorize.args="xx")

plot(0:max(failures),cumsum(table(factor(failures,levels=0:max(failures))))/nn,
    type="h",xlab="",ylab="",las=1)
lines(0:max(failures), cdf_sk(0:max(failures)))
lines(0:max(failures), cdf_muxo(0:max(failures)),col="red")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the labor of love!  The Wikipedia article is problematic.  I am following the convention in its formula box in the right, which defines $r$ is the number of failures.  $k$ is the number of successes, starting from 0, 1, ...  If that is my convention for $x$, $r$, $k$ and $p$, is my CDF formula correct?

Comment: I don't think so. I have tried to implement it as you wrote it up, and as you see, it does not work. Even if you start your summation at $i=0$, it does not seem to be the same as mine. (Which I'll admit I trust, because it gives the same results as a simulation. I always like simulating as an added reassurance. Have you tried simulating your CDF?)

Comment: I do not know how to use R.  =(

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way we can think to a Pascal random variable $X_{n}$ with distribution $\mathcal{NB}(p,n)$ is to think at it as a sum of $Y_{1}+\cdots+Y_{n}$ of $n$ random independant with equal geometric distribution $\mathcal{G}(p)-1$.

Infact you can notice this considering $Y_{i}$ as the random variable which keeps tracks of the failures betweeen the $(i-1)$-th and $i$-th success. $Y_{i}$ are clearly independant and have distribution of parameter $p$ minus 1 because the geometric distribution counts the number of trial needed in order to gain a success, which correspond to the number of failures and the the final success.

In this way is easier to verify your distribution correctness. You can find some reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Is my formula correct?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = k) = \binom{k+n-1}{k}p^{n}(1-p)^{k}$. So $\mathbb{P}(X_{n} \leq j) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = i) =  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j}  \binom{i+n-1}{i}p^{n}(1-p)^{i}$

Comment: Replacing $n$ and $j$ in your formula with $k$ and $x$, and shift $i$ to start from 1 (assume 1 failure / 1 trial minimum), I suppose my updated formula matches yours?

Comment: @muxo It doesn't seem to me since if you shift the index $(1-p)$ will be shifted, and it will be different